# Debugging with Maven SureFire Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: junit5

I am getting the following error when I debug in Eclipse.

I have debugged configuration where goal = -Dmaven.surefire.debug clean install
and remote java application configuration where host=localhost and port=5005.
This was working where it would let me debug the junit test case and stop working.

```
 ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
    [ERROR] ExecutionException The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
    [ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\JAVA\jdk8\jre\bin\java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire425261856307162974\surefirebooter7580221845135250781.jar C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire425261856307162974 2019-04-19T18-06-49_005-jvmRun1 surefire891482895950174726tmp surefire_05373426221847918704tmp"
    [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
    [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 2
    [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: ExecutionException The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
    [ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\JAVA\jdk8\jre\bin\java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire425261856307162974\surefirebooter7580221845135250781.jar C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire425261856307162974 2019-04-19T18-06-49_005-jvmRun1 surefire891482895950174726tmp surefire_05373426221847918704tmp"
    [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
    [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 2
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.awaitResultsDone(ForkStarter.java:511)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkOnceMultiple(ForkStarter.java:383)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:298)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:247)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1161)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1002)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:848)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    [ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    [ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    [ERROR] Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

Comment: Do not put error like this. Instead of error code, you can put the screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the port 5005 is already in use.
assuming that you are using windows you can use the below command to find the PID of the process listening to the port 5005, you will get the list of all the listening pids and ports and you have to check the 5005 one

```
netstat -aon | find /i "listening"
```

on linux it is easy

```
lsof -i:5005
```

once you have the PID you can kill it using below
on windows

```
taskkill /F /PID {PID}
```

on linux/mac

```
kill -9 {PID}
```

then try to debug the maven test and it should work.